# Bootstrap Alert Messages After Ajax Put Request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to enable bootstrap alerts when a checkbox is clicked on a form of mine.  I'm currently updating the records via ajax, here is the controller in rails:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if assignment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
    format.js {}
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Changed"
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

that then triggers a path request at `app/views/roles/assign.js.erb` which I currently have this in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
});
```

I was hoping I could play in debugger but I can't even get in there.

My ajax looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function update_user() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/roles/assign/',
      type: 'PUT',
      data: {'assignment': this.name}
    });
  }
  $(".role-check").on( "click", update_user );
});
```

The records are saving correctly in ActiveRecord and saving accordingly - I just can't get the alert to show up without a page reload.

Here is my `application.html.haml`

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Qautamator
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render '/layouts/header'
    .container
      .flash_notice
        - flash.each do |name, msg|
          %div{:class => "alert alert-#{flash_level(name)}"}
            %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"}
              %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} &times;
              %span.sr-only Close
            = msg
      = yield
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable and use it for the flash messages.

**in your controller**

```
respond_to do |format|
  if assignment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
    @status= "Success"
    format.js {}
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Changed"
    @status= "Changed"
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

**add this in application.html.haml**

```
.text-success.profile_image_added.alert.alert-success.text-center
```

**add this to app/views/roles/assign.js.erb**

```
#####no need->$(document).ready(function() {
$(".profile_image_added').html("<%= @status %>"):
#####no need->    });
```

Comment: add the class to `application.html.haml`? The jquery then goes in `assign.js.erb`?

Comment: @Anthony...i have updated my answer..pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I know what you are looking for but on your ajax request couldn't you add a `success` handler that displays your message?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function update_user() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/roles/assign/',
      type: 'PUT',
      data: {'assignment': this.name},
      success:  function (response) {
        alert(response); //or whatever method of displaying to user
      }
    });
  }
  $(".role-check").on( "click", update_user );
});
```